# How to force camera to take squared pictures in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera, ios7

In iOS 7 the camera comes with several modes: video, photo, square and pano. In the application I am developing, we allow users to use the camera to take pictures. We only want squared pictures so we make users crop images afterwards.

Is it possible to programmatically force the camera to only take squared pictures?

This is my code to open the camera:

```
-(void) openImagePickerSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)type
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = type;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

I have been looking at the documentation but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

UIImagePickerController has a property called 'allowsEditing'. That will open the Camera in full screen and allows you to resize the taken photo after shot.

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
```

you can get the photo in the protocol method using a key 'UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage'.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *pic = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```